# Mysql join for 4 table with multiple rows in codeingiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, join

I would like to perform a mysql join for 4 table, here is how they look like

**student_details**, will contain student details with rows having unique value

```
------------------------------------------
| student_unique | name | age | etc...
------------------------------------------
|  1232432       | ABC  | 23  | xxx
|  1223233       | CDE  | 26  | yyy
------------------------------------------
```

**student_subjects** list of subjects student enrolled in

```
-------------------------------
| student_unique | subject_id |
-------------------------------
|  1232432       | 25         |
|  1232432       | 26         |
-------------------------------
```

**subject_details** details of subject

```
-------------------------------
| subject_id | subject_name   |
-------------------------------
|  25        | chemistry      |
|  12        | english        |
-------------------------------
```

**Student_contact_details** list of student contact details

```
-------------------------------------
| student_unique | key   | value    |
-------------------------------------
|  1232432       | email | a@b.com
|  1232432       | phone | 555-44-333
-------------------------------------
```

Now I want to run the query to find all details for student `1232432` and result should be like this

- 1 Row from **student_details** table
- 2 rows from **student_subjects** table
- 2 rows from **subject_details** table
- 2 rows from **student_contact_details** table

**HERE IS WHAT I'VE DONE**

```
$this->db->select(
                'a.student_unique,
                a.name,
                b.student_unique,
                b.subject_id,
                c.subject_id,
                c.subject_name,
                d.student_unique,
                d.key,
                d.value,'
            );
            $this->db->from('student_details a');
            $this->db->join('student_subjects b', 'b.student_unique = a.student_unique', 'left');
            $this->db->join('subject_details c', 'c.subject_id = b.subject_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('student_contact_details d','d.student_unique = b.student_unique', 'right');
            $this->db->where('a.student_unique',$student_unique);
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Please paste your desired output in a tabular format. Student subjects and student contact details are 2 different entities with no relation, it is better to keep them different by firing 2 queries or else you will end up getting duplicate rows.

Comment: if you will use inner join you will get this

`1 1232432 ABC 23 25 chemistry email a@b.com`
`1 1232432 ABC 23 25 chemistry phone 55-44-333`

thats what you want